# Deserialize json into __dict__ has odd behaviour

Tags: python, json, dictionary, serialization, attributes

in python 2.7.13, I have a class which in the `__init__` does this:

```
self.__dict__ = json.load(f, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

But when I run it on my PC, it act as expected: deserializing the json file elements as class attributes, so that `self.__dict__` actually contains same elements.

Instead in other people computers it created a further sub `__dict__` dictionary as attribute of the class, which means that json elements are inside `self.__dict__["__dict__"]` or something similar.

It means instead than replacing `self.__dict__` elements with those from the json, it just creates a further namesake (`__dict__`) dictionary inside `self.__dict__`.

Do you have any idea why it act so differently for different users and how to prevent it?

Comment: Step 1, kill Python 2. You need to be using Python 3. Step two: don't unpack into `__dict__`; instead, pass `**json.load()` into the kwargs of the constructor.

Comment: I have my doubts that the exact same code and the exact same input file is producing different results. Either the `self.__dict__ =` is running in a context where `__setattr__` or something is causing the nested dict, or the JSON file contains an object with `__dict__` as a ket.

Comment: @Reinderien doesn't depend on me. I'm coding additional functions for an application which only supports python 2.7.13 for scripting. I'll check for the kwargs suggestion, if it can apply. Surely I need a more reliable way than mine to do it.

Comment: @AlexHall I don't know if the context can differ between users. Anyway there's no `__dict__` into the json: it is the same json for all users, it just changes how elements are valorized.
Pratically the class is an "options collector", so it reads json with all customized options and then offer them as attributes to the main script. But the options are the same for all users.
EDIT: checked in Internet: do you mean overriding `def __setattr__`? If that, the answer is no. We have same identical script.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this worked:

```
self.__dict__.update(json.load(f, encoding='utf-8-sig'))
```

The update function add a dictionary elements with those from another dictionary.
Using it on `__dict__` enriches currenct class' attributes with those elements from the dictionary returned by `json.load` file deserializer function.